# Android + Phonegap Build + Google Analytics working example

Tags: android, cordova, google-analytics, phonegap-build

What I have tried:

- [GAPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/GAPlugin) plugin with no luck. (I have added a JS exception handler to catch errors and are not receiving anything) The Result Handler from the plugin returns success but I see no stats.  On my desktop browser I get an error that it can get to the `GAPlugin` that is normal.
- Analytics.js as per [Google Universal Analytics with PhoneGap Apps](http://www.blastam.com/blog/index.php/2013/07/ga-universal-analytics-phonegap-mobile-apps) . This actually records GA activity from my desktop browser but does not work from my mobile and also does not report any errors.
- Have tried the above on Galaxy S1, Galaxy S4 and Galaxy S Tab.

My feeling is its to do with the `file://` protocol.

Does anyone have a working example?

[My Code](https://github.com/Protoneer/test/tree/master/test7): `index.html` uses the *Plugin* and `index.html.old` uses *Analytics.js*

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine for me. I use the GAPlugin in 3 different apps and it works fine.

If you set it up exactly the way it says to do it in the GAPlugin docs it should work.

I use an initialisation script that runs in $(document).ready:

```
function analyticsInit() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
    console.log('initializeGAplugin');    
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    gaPlugin = window.plugins.gaPlugin;
    gaPlugin.init(nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler, "GA number", 10);
}
```

And then, to avoid errors in the browser:

```
function myTrackerFunction() {
    if(localStorage.trackpermission==="trackon" && typeof gaPlugin !== "undefined"){
        gaPlugin.trackEvent( nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler, "Button", "Click", "WhatImTracking", 1);
    }    
}
```